# Redirect with ? in URL - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, uri, redirection

I have Domain Access instaled, but not very sure if that is the problem: I have several domains under the same installation. It all works perfectly, but when I try to enter **www.example.com**/?q=user, it only works for some of the domains, for others it redirects to the home, and this causes other problems.

I have revised .htaccess (even installed a fresh copy), I have seen in the database, and cannot trace the problem, which is completely consistent. When using the same config in localhost (home PC), the problem is not found, so there is some incompatibility that came accros the project.

Any suggestion? I have Clean URLs switched on, but because it depends on any domain config, I cannot be sure because don't know where it stores the data, apparently it does work perfectly (don't understand ? in a content node, for example).

Comment: Are all of your domains active/enabled?

Comment: Yes, and working perfectly. The only problem was with the thumbnails of images created, which were broken, and only are activated when visited with other domain. Curiously, with those domains which do not show the problem above. It is very strange. I have download the exact data from the host and trying to reproduce locally with the same data, because all attempts have been a failure. The problem is consistent, and I discovered were related (not creating image thumbnail, which uses ? in the URL as a process, and  redirection when trying to enter the user login in the old fashion with ?q=user

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem. It is a malfunction of module or submodule Domain Locale. If you have a domain whose list of languages does not contain your default language (main site), then it doesn't work. All the project to the trash, months of development ruined.